# I have encountered #Name? error in access form

Tags: database, forms, access-control, ms-access-2016, ms-access-forms

In Access Database I have main Form named "frmMain" and child form "frmPaymentsToAllAccountsTotal". The Child form is continuous Form I create a textbox on Main form and named "mrdPayments". In the control source of this text box I enter this expression
=[Forms]![frmPaymentsToAllAccountsTotal]![AnasT], where "AnasT" is textbox in footer of sub form. Whenever I go to form view. I got #name? error. Please note that there is no space before and after the field name, form name. I notice when I open child form separately then mrdPayments showing value as expected but as I close the sub form even sub form is already placed on Main form, then mrdPayments value changes to #name? error.

I am using MS Access 2019, 64 bit version on Windows 10

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed control of mrdPayments from =[Forms]![frmPaymentsToAllAccountsTotal]![AnasT] to
=[frmPaymentsToAllAccountsTotal].[Form]![AnasT] on Main Form and my problem solved.

Comment: You can close this question by clicking the green checkmark to the left of your answer.